# Performance JSON x Properties em Java

Tags: java, json, desempenho, gson, propriedade

Boa noite.
Eu costumava utilizar vários arquivos *.properties* para salvar os dados da aplicação desktop que eu desenvolvo. Estudei a possibilidade de trocar esses arquivos por arquivos *.json*, pois vejo que muitos softwares do mercado utilizam esse formato.
Ao realizar a troca, percebi uma perda de performance ao carregar os dados.
Então gostaria de fazer algumas perguntas:
**1)** Existe alguma *boa prática* que possa melhorar o desempenho da aplicação?
**2)** Para salvar diversos arquivos, cada um contendo um objeto java inserido pelo usuário através da aplicação, *.json* é a melhor opção ou existe outra melhor?
A ideia desses arquivos é facilitar a portabilidade de um computador para outro e a troca de informações entre usuários diferentes.
Segue o link do commit que fiz com a troca:
https://github.com/coppolaop/DungeonManager/commit/0ac90b905f02156eef43838b5f2960bf776cba15

Fiquem à vontade para fomentar o debate, acho que pode agregar bastante.
Agradeço desde já pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei [um artigo](https://blog.overops.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/) falando sobre a performance das bibliotecas de conversão. A pesquisa citada nele compara as bibliotecas mais utilizadas, estou levando ele como resposta da minha **primeira pergunta**, a *boa prática* depende do projeto e de seus frameworks. Sobre a **segunda pergunta**, continuo acreditando que é uma questão de convenção, como a comunidade adota bastante o JSON atualmente, devido ao REST, acredito que é uma boa opção.